# How can I solve this mysql? Do it with php or mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is...

```
 SELECT m.msgFrom, m.msgTo, m.msgID, m.subject, m.dateTime, a.username 
 FROM mailbox m 
 JOIN accounts a ON (m.msgFrom = a.id) 
 WHERE msgTo = $user 
      OR msgFrom = $user 
      AND parentID = 0 
 ORDER BY dateTime DESC 
 LIMIT 250
```

Is it possible to change this query so that the `ON` changes depending on the value of `msgTo` or `msgFrom`.

I have a user variable. If the user variable equals `msgTo` get the `username` where the `id` equals `msgFrom`. If the user variable equals `msgFrom` get the `username` where the `id` equals `msgTo`?

I hope I explained it well enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an `IF` statement within the `ON` clause. This will join with the account of the opposite user. (i.e. if the message is *from* `$user`, then `username` will be for the receiving user and if the message is *to* `$user`, then `username` will be for the sending user.)

```
SELECT m.msgFrom, m.msgTo, m.msgID, m.subject, m.dateTime, a.username 
FROM mailbox m JOIN accounts a ON a.id=IF(msgTo=$user, msgFrom, msgTo)
WHERE msgTo = $user OR msgFrom = $user AND parentID = 0 
ORDER BY dateTime DESC LIMIT 250
```

Comment: Is the if the same syntax as a ternary in php?

Comment: It's not the same syntax, but the order of the clauses are the same. That is, first comes the condition, then second, the value if true, and finally the value if false.

Comment: Worked first time awesome. Got to wait to except.

Comment: I believe you're missing a closing paranthesis

Comment: I should downvote for that, yea? I won't though, I'm not an ass